# Cannot install Oracle tools for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, odt.net

I am trying to install the file ODTwithODAC121021 on a Windows 8.1 VM running on parallels and get the following error message when I run the Oracle universal installer

```
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors Higher than
256 .    Actual 4294967296     Passed
 Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\OraInstall2015-10-21_03-53-37PM. Please wait ... [../stage/Components/ora
cle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/._filegroup1.jar]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
[../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/._filegroup2.jar]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
[../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/._filegroup3.jar]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
[../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/._filegroup4.jar]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
[../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/._filegroup5.jar]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Any ideas? Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Disregard my posting. The file was corrupt